# Java EE CDI Interceptor not working when annotation has parameters

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, interceptor, java-ee-7

I want to write a CDI interceptor. The interception works well if my annotation only contains 1 parameter but breaks if 2 parameters are used. The question is why?

The interceptor class:

```
@Monitored
@Interceptor
@Priority(APPLICATION)
public class MonitoringInterceptor {

    @AroundInvoke 
    public Object logInvocation(InvocationContext ctx) throws Exception {
        LOGGER.error("METHOD CALLED!!!"); //this is not called when annotation has 2 parameters
        return ctx.proceed();
    }
}
```

The annotation:

```
@InterceptorBinding
@Target({TYPE, METHOD})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Inherited
public @interface Monitored {
    public String layer() default "BUSINESS";
    public String useCase() default "N/A";
}
```

Now the interesting part:

```
@Stateless
public class MyBean {

    //this does not work, why?
    @Monitored(layer = "BUSINESS", useCase = "test")

    //if I use the following annotation it works well
    //@Monitored(layer = "BUSINESS")
    public String sayHello(String message) {
        return message; 
    }
}
```

I know that `MyBean` is not annotated with `@Interceptors`. This is intended. The interceptor is declared in `beans.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
   bean-discovery-mode="all">
<interceptors>
    <class>my.package.MonitoringInterceptor</class>
</interceptors>
</beans>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The parameters are part of the binding. Either annotate the parameters with `@Nonbinding`, or make sure the same values are used for the interceptor as well as for the intercepting point.

Comment: Thank you, after adding `@Nonbinding` to the parameters it worked.